# Bluetooth HCI Snooping integrity

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-le

For a project I am sniffing bluetooth communication between an embedded device and my android phone. To make this work I enabled the Bluetooth HCI Snoop log option on my Android phone in developer options. The bluetooth used is Bluetooth LE (Bluetooth Smart)

The embedded device communicates through bluetooth with an app installed on my Android device. Opening the created log file with Wireshark I found some interesting results. I compared my results to that of an example bluetooth capture file and noticed that about half of communication is not present in my capture log.

In my capture log there is no PIN code request/reply, no connection events (only disconnect), no link key messages and no SDP or L2CAP protocol usage.

I don't understand why I am getting these strange results and I  wonder if the entire bluetooth connection and communication process between embedded and android device (including the app) is not captured